# next(err) not working in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, middleware

I have the issue that my `next(err)` is not working. It ignores error and just loads the page instead of sending HTTP status code 404.

The ldap search works fine and result looks as expected. It just doesn't return error when the else statement is hit.
The console does show the `failed` in log

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    conn.search('dc=foo', opts, function (err, res) {

        assert.ifError(err)
        var entries = []

        res.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {

            entries.push(entry.object)
        })

        res.on('end', function (result) {

            conn.unbind(function (err) {

                console.log('Disconnecting')

                if (entries.length == 1) {
                    next()
                } else {
                    console.log('fail')
                    var err = new Error('Permission Denied')
                    err.status = 404
                    next(err)
                }
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Hmmm that's a nice 4-level deep callback hell. Are you sure `res.on('end')` is supposed to be inside `res.on('searchEntry')`?

Comment: haha yea my bad was typing in not cp/paste. And I always seem to mess up indentation in here

Comment: `res.on('end')` is still inside `res.on('searchEntry')`... Nobody will be able to help if you give us the wrong code

Comment: guy its an easy mistake to make to miss something whilst retyping.

Comment: I know, but you're looking for help and not giving us the right code so... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Now that's the right code, so where is `next` defined?

Comment: As above with app.use I use in a different function and works fine

Comment: I don't think `next` works like that. If you do not want your next middleware to be called, don't call `next()` at all. Use `return res.status(404).end()`.

Comment: well no this function is a replacement for the previous one. as that uses a white list, this is now ldap

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `next` works like that. If you do not want your next middleware to be called, don't call `next(error)` or `next()` at all. Use instead :

```
if (entries.length == 1) {
     next()
} else {
     console.log('fail')
     return res.status(404).send('Permission Denied')
}
```

Comment: thanks but that crashes the app with ```TypeError: res.status is not a function```

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, because `res.status()` is definitely part of [express API](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html).

Comment: Im not saying it isn't, I mnot doing anyhing wrong Ive followed ldapjs. my search works. That just doesnt work for some reason. so wind in the attitude. If it worked I wouldnt be here right?

Comment: Wow dude don't be so touchy :) Despite you thinking that you're not doing anything wrong, you _are_ doing something wrong, because 1) your code doesn't work, 2) res.status is part of the API so it should be defined, so you're not passing the right `res` object. I'm just stating the obvious, not insulting you here.

Comment: I'm pulling in the right ```res``` object as I can see it in the ```console.log(res.status)``` gives me a 0 which is what I'd expect from ldapjs

Comment: Oh, so you're not using Express? Maybe that's why we're not going anywhere with that :) I've never heard of ldapjs

Comment: I'm using Express, but then LDAPjs to querry the LDAP server, looks like res was being overwritten by LDAPjs. so I have sorted that issue. Now trying to get it to 404